# Selenium web scraping not working as expected

Tags: python

the aim is to extract data from websites that offer certifications. the code should go through the elements of the courses and go to the next page, but it doesn't work well because on page 2 it stops, why?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 


chromedriver_path = '/Users/charl/Downloads/chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,9)

driver.get('https://www.coursera.org/search?query=python')

# close cookies popup
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler')))
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler'))).click()

course_data = {key:[] for key in ['Título','Puntuación','Descripción', 'Institución', 'Dificultad, Tipo, Duración']}
#course_data = {key:[] for key in ['Título','Puntuación','Descripción', 'Institución']}
page_count = 10

for page in range(page_count):

    print(f'current page: {driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*=current]").text}', end='\r')  #elements?
    
    courses = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'main ul>li')))
    for course in courses:
        course_data['Título']       += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("a[class*=CommonCard-title]")?.innerText', course)]
        course_data['Descripción'] += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("div[class*=ProductCard-body]")?.innerText', course)]  #div+p bueno #p:has(>span) #h2 + p
        course_data['Puntuación']      += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("div[class*=CommonCard-ratings]")?.innerText.replace("\\n\\n","⭐")', course)]
        course_data['Institución']       += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("span")?.innerText', course)]
        course_data['Dificultad, Tipo, Duración']       += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("div[class*=CommonCard-metadata]")?.innerText', course)] #div+p #div:last-child p

    next_btn = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Next Page"]')
    for next_btn in next_btn:
        next_btn.click()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(course_data)
df.to_csv('course_data.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

df.head(10)

#df
```

Comment: You must provide debugging data to know in which part you are not retrieving the object you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get empty data because the css selectors inside get_title, get_review and get_description are wrong. Moreover, all the code about creating a csv, adding a row etc can be replaced by a single line `df.to_csv(path)`: initiliaze a dictionary to store data, add data as you loop over courses, finally create a dataframe and export it as a csv.

Moreover, when you get titles, reveiws and descriptions, you can replace the try except blocks with a single javascript line (`driver.execute_script(javascript_code)`). How? For example consider

```
return document.querySelector("h2")?.innerText
```

and focus on the part `?.innerText`. What it means is: if `querySelector` finds something then execute `.innerText`, otherwise don't execute it. Moreover, in the second case `driver.execute_script()` returns `None`.

So you can easily get the courses data with the following code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromedriver_path = ''
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,9)

driver.get('https://www.coursera.org/search?query=python')

# close cookies popup
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler')))
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler'))).click()

course_data = {key:[] for key in ['title','rating','description', 'metadata']}
page_count = 2000

for page in range(page_count):

    current_page_btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*=current]")))
    print(f'current page: {current_page_btn.text}', end='\r')
    
    courses = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'main ul>li')))
    for course in courses:
        course_data['title']       += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("a[class*=CommonCard-title]")?.innerText', course)]
        course_data['description'] += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("div[class*=ProductCard-body]")?.innerText', course)]
        course_data['rating']      += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("div[class*=CommonCard-ratings]")?.innerText.replace("\\n\\n","⭐")', course)]
        course_data['metadata']    += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("div[class*=CommonCard-metadata]")?.innerText', course)]
        
    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Next Page"]')
    if 'disabled' in next_btn.get_attribute('class'):
       print('There are no more pages')
       break
    else:
        next_btn.click()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(course_data)
df.to_csv('course_data.csv', index=False)
```

If you print `df` you will see something like this. Notice the `None` value at line 9, it means that the reviews data where not present for that course.

[image]

Comment: could u please share the whole code to see how u were able to run it? I updated the code and now I´m getting at least data from it but I have to check it again. Thanks for your time, appreciate it

Comment: @Carlosplaza I added full code, check it out and let me know

Comment: I'm still testing the code, when I have a more concrete answer I'll let you know. How have you been able to get the data,  to be seen in such a visual way?
Because I have tried with df.head() and print(df) but it doesn't get them like that.

Comment: @Carlosplaza What are you using to run the code? I use jupyter notebook and run the command `display(df)`

Comment: python on visual studio

Comment: @Carlosplaza You can use notebooks in visual studio as i show in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBSmc.png). As you can see notebooks have extension `.ipynb`, but i think you need to install jupyter notebook to be able to open it in visual code

Comment: it looks like it worked! Appreciate it man. Is there any way to update the code to to make the data extraction automatic, let's imagine if we pass as value page_count = 2000, or would there be problems?

Comment: @Carlosplaza When you reach the last page the "next button" becomes disabled (i.e. you cannot click on it anymore) and a new class `disabled` is added to the button. So we can easily check this by adding `'disabled' in next_btn.get_attribute('class')`. I updated the code check it and let me know

Comment: the last few days I've been having some problems with the IDE, and now the python file automatically closes the browser window, it prints the current page but subsequently deletes it and returns to the console., however the .ipynb file seems to work fine. What can this be due to?

Comment: and also, what's the point of printing the page, because it will always be 1, right? because when you open the browser it will start with page 1 of the website.

Comment: @Carlosplaza The page is 1 only at the first loop, then it clicks the next button page and so it goes to page 2 and so on. If the problem is solved consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking ✓ on the left

Comment: Currently, I guess after some change in your website, I am having problems accessing the element indicating the difficulty, both the type of course and the duration. I suppose it would be the child element of <p>, could you help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Carlosplaza The CSS of `description` has changed from `h2+p` to `h2+div+p`. To target difficulty, course type and duration you can use `div:has(>svg)+p`

Comment: could u please update the code again? I´m having several problems with the script. Is there any way to automate the script to locate the elements automatically when they change and not to indicate their path manually? thanks in advance

Comment: @Carlosplaza I updated the code, now I use webelements classes instead of relative positions between webelements. So it will work even if their positions inside the css structure are changed

Comment: I havep updated my code also, could u please help me with that?

Comment: @making I thought you were running my code, why are you using a different one?